# Invalid merchant configuration for paypal Direct Credit card payment

Tags: php, paypal

We have used DoDirectMethod to credit card payment and recurring payment with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Method. But Some how i can not get error "This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.".

I found some solution for this : 
1)I have problem like : Features that are not enabled for live transactions[image]

2) If for use of REST API ,
I need to change my country then how can i change country or currency.

3) In paypal errorcode i found : Occurs when you have not agreed to the billing agreement.
- Then how can i agreed billing agrrement- need steps for it.

Please help me by providing steps of configuration or any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal is confusing peoples/developers completely, i am also getting the same issue from one month on one of our client's website, i was used DoDirectPayment, and it works like a charm for test transactions, but as i make it LIVE it is was showing the same issue, i found that too, to performing transactions in LIVE mode we need to 'Enable' this feature for Direct Credit Cards, but many times i requested them (PayPal) to enable that feature, but all time they just received my Application Online and reponsed that it will take about 24 hours. I have also added extra information like SSN, EIN all that but they are so lazy or not active to do that.

At one point they are saying we need Website Payments Pro but i have not found a single link to register that, I found PayPal Payments Pro link at many sites and even in their site, these guys have a huge documentation on that website payments pro and dodirect method but not a single link how to register for that service or how they enable that feature for 'Live' mode.

And today i found they updated their developers site and make things a little different, also provided an extra method "braintreegateway" in order to process, and i tried that too using their sandbox account, its working with only PHP 5.4 and above, so old PHP version servers are unable to get that. And they also need to register your details at their end.

If i have already a PayPal Business account why do i need to register at every single method.

Sucked